# Word for someone who jumps ship when things get hard?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What is the word that captures the attitude of escaping a circumstance when things seem to get hard or are going bad.

Comment: Sometimes this attitude may be the correct course of action!

Comment: Why does this question have to be protected? A newcomer with 0 rep provided an excellent citation that contains a poetic and descriptive expression. If this question had been protected, they would never have posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traitor, weasel, chicken, deserter, opportunist - these words all have some nuances of a person who does not/can not follow through when the going gets hard or you need to depend on that person and they can't be found when the chips are down.

Answer (score 9):

Precisely your title metaphor is captured in the traditional “rats deserting a sinking ship”.

[bookbrowse.com](http://www.bookbrowse.com/wordplay/archive/detail/index.cfm?wordplay_number=114) gives this background:

> Rats have been said to be the first to sense an impending disaster, such as a sinking ship or a gas leak in a mine—so if rats are seen leaving it's a good idea to follow!
>
> Early records of this expression go back all the way to Pliny The Elder's *Natural History (77 AD): 'When a building is about to fall down, all the mice desert it'.
>
> It also appears in a form closer to the modern usage in Shakespeare's *The Tempest*, Act I, Scene II (1610):
>
> *Prospero*: In few, they hurried us aboard a bark,
>      Bore us some leagues to sea; where they prepar'd
>      A rotten carcass of a boat, not rigg'd,
>      Nor tackle, sail, nor mast; the very rats
>      Instinctively had quit it.

Comment: +1 because I think you're right, but I do think our metaphorical ***rat*** has increasingly taken on connotations of [backstabber, betrayer, sneak, snitch, etc.](http://thesaurus.com/browse/snitch). Not that shipboard rats would ever have been the sailor's "friend", but Russell's obliquely-reference *"fair-weather friend"* is a more likely expression today in OP's context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I agree that you need the whole phrase, not just "rats". A single word is hard. "Bandwagoner" works, but from the far side.

Comment: +1 '*Rats*' should be the word that comes to mind first. And for all the  right reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Quitter

Maybe coward, depending on the details.

Answer (score 4):

"Fair weather sailor" - even fits your 'jump ship' metaphor.

[Urban dictionary - fair weather sailor](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fair-weather%20sailor)

- fair-weather sailor
  See fair-weather friend.
  Someone who is agreeable only when the prevailing conditions are pleasant.
  Unreliable when the going gets rough.

Comment: I think that Urban Dictionary link has little credibility. ["fair-weather friend"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22fair-weather+friend%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) gets 14,600 hits on Google Books, practically every one of which will match OP's context. Whereas ["fair-weather sailor"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22fair-weather+sailor%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) gets only 3280, and every one I looked at was for the literal meaning *inexperienced sailor who's never been tested by the weather*.

Comment: ...(but *fair-weather **friend*** is spot on, so no downvote! :)

Answer (score 3):

Thomas Paine called them summer soldiers and sunshine patriots.

"These are the times that try men's souls: The summer soldier and the sunshine patriot will, in this crisis, shrink from the service of his country; but he that stands it now, deserves the love and thanks of man and woman."

Source:  [Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/175410-these-are-the-times-that-try-men-s-souls-the-summer)

Comment: Good quote! Please add a source and a link in your future answers.

Answer (score 2):

~ Abandoner
~ deserter
~ betrayer
~ turncoat

Comment: +1 deserter = fugitive from responsibility

Comment: Note a "betrayer" or "turncoat" is not someone who gives up, but actively joins the opposing side.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a verbal phrase instead of a noun, you could use ***wimp out***, ***bail out***, or ***punch out***.  NOAD says:

> **wimp out**: withdraw from a course of action or a stated position in a way that is seen as feeble or cowardly.
>
> **bail out**: (of a member of an aircrew) make an emergency parachute descent from an aircraft; eject.
>
> • *figurative* become free of an obligation or commitment; discontinue
> an activity: *she felt ready to bail out of the corporate rat race*

As for *punch out*, NOAD says:

> **punch out**: register one's departure from work, esp. by means of a time clock

but *punch out* can also be used synonymously with bail out (of an aircraft)<sup>1</sup>. So, essentially, *punch out* can work in two ways at once: it can mean to eject (from a flight) or to quit (from work).  In some contexts, that can express the meaning you want:

> *Paul punched out on us; he ran to the prosecuter and copped a plea!*

You might also consider ***wuss*** (or ***wussy***). NOAD says:

> ***wuss***: *a weak or ineffectual person*

I've also heard the word *wuss* used to indicate the opposite of *tough and resolute*, which seems like what you're trying to convey.

---

<sup>1</sup>For example, *“In late June another pilot was lost when he punched out after reporting unspecified problems.”* (Barrett Tillman, *MiG Master: The Story of the F-8 Crusader*, 1980, p. 93).